# Create symbolic link of a folder

Tags: linux, symlink

Into the folder `/usr/local/var` I would like to create a symbolic link `run` that point to `/var/run` folder. But I'm quite bit confused how to correctly create the link. Should I create  initially the `run` folder?

Comment: This is more appropriate for SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it like this without the need of creating something before:

```
 ln -s /usr/local/var /var/run
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are **windows users** and want to *create a symbolic link* of a folder is here how:

**NOTE:** Just make sure you run the **command prompt as administrator**.

**WINDOWS**

```
mklink /d "D:\site\abc\js" "F:\xyz\js"
```

**MAC**

```
ln -s /usr/local/var /var/run
```