# Use ram disk for building Vaadin 8 web app in IntelliJ 2017.1

Tags: intellij-idea, compilation, vaadin, compiler-optimization, ramdisk

I would like to speed up compile/build process when making a Maven-based [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) 8 app in [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) 2017.1, as well as avoid chewing up my flash-based storage needlessly, by outputting intermediate and final products on a [ram drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive).

How to configure IntelliJ or my project to use a ram disk?

I am currently running the Vaadin app using the built-in Jetty Servlet container using the included Maven task. In the future I expect to have IntelliJ coordinate with a separate installation of Tomcat Servlet container.

Some perusing revealed:

- `Project Structure` > `Project` > `Project compiler output`
- `Project Structure` > `Modules` > `Paths` (tab) > `Compiler output`
- `Project Structure` > `Artifacts`

Are any or all of those required to be redirected to the ram disk?

Is there a faster, easier, or simpler way to configure output to a ram disk? Perhaps some trick with the Maven POM file?

By comparison, this approach is used by many iOS/macOS developers using [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) who divert their `DerivedData` folder to a RAM disk to speed up the compiling process.

Comment: Relocating [IDE cache](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207240985) may also help.

Comment: Does copying your project folder into your ram drive and opening it from there work for you?

Comment: @petey Copying entire project is less than optimal because of risk of loss in case of OS crash or otherwise losing the RAM disk. Plus it means the hassle of copying back and forth for every work session. Writing only temporary files and build artifacts and final complied output to the RAM disk would be much safer.

Comment: I think I found your answer in these previously asked questions about maven build locations : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908013/maven-how-to-change-path-to-target-directory-from-command-line
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587375/how-to-change-maven-build-directory

Comment: If the above answers are too complex, try a symbolic link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347465/create-symbolic-link-of-a-folder